# How to store functions in an Object?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to store multiple functions in one object.  However, my current code seems to overwrite the previous data.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733591/309535

Because it is a loop with other stuff going on, the code cannot be within the same block of  javascript.

My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var at = {
  atleft_1: function drawChart() {
    // data goes here
  }
 }
 </script>
```

// Next loop

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var at = {
  atleft_2: function drawChart() {
    // data goes here
  }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `at` is already defined, just assign a property:

```
var at = {};
at.atleft_1 = function.....;
at.atleft_2 = function.....;
```

Although by the look of it you may be better of with:

```
at.atleft = function(id) {...};
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works now!

Comment: You can also, at each iteration, do: `var at = at || {};`. If `at` is defined, it will take the existing, or create a new object if it doesn't exists...

Answer (score 0):

You Can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var at = {
     atleft_2: function() {
         // data goes here
    },
    atleft_1: function(){
       //data goes here
   }
};
</script>
```

Why are you using drawChart?? I didn't get it.

Comment: Drawchart is from Google Charts.  Adding multiple graphs to one page.  This was the best method I could figure out. . . http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

Comment: so you should call that function with those functions.