# Creating javascript function with variable name and accessing it?

Tags: javascript

i have a scenario where javascript function name needs to be  decided at run time. For simplicity assume i have function name in javascript variable and now i want to create the function using variable value. I went thru the link [Javascript - Variable in function name, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733580/javascript-variable-in-function-name-possible)  and tried the small code snippet

```
   <HTML>
       <HEAD>
          <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
      </HEAD>
        <script>
        var temp1='at_26';
        temp1: function() {alert("Inside 26"); }
        </script>
         <BODY>
            <a href="javascript:window[at_26]()">Copy Text</a>
         </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

But when i click on hyperlink Copy Text it gives error saying **Line: 1
Error: 'at_26' is undefined**

Comment: Too bad I cannot vote comments down!

Comment: The question you linked to does not show anything regarding `temp1: function() {alert("Inside 26"); }`. Where do you get this from? This is invalid JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMOs](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/JJCva/)

```
var temp1='at_26'; 
window[temp1]=function() {alert("Inside 26"); return false}
```

and then

```
<a href="#" onclick="return window['at_26']()">Click</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#" onclick="return at_26()">Click</a>
```

should work

What I THINK you want since it does not pollute the global scope and is using a colon like in your example is this:

```
var myScope = {
  "at_26":function() {alert("Inside 26"); return false}
}
```

using

```
<a href="#" onclick="return myScope.at_26()">Click</a><br />
```

Comment: Yes, it is. `window[temp1]` resolves as `window['at_26']`, and the function is assigned there. Nowhere do you say `window['temp1'] = function` or `temp1 = function`.

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple issues in your code. A corrected version will be like:

```
<script>
    window['at_26'] = function() {alert("Inside 26"); };
</script>
<BODY>
    <a href="javascript:window['at_26']()">Copy Text</a>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Why the downvote (apart from not fixing the horrible javascript pseudo protocol)

Comment: @techfoobar my question is creating the function name with variable name.you have hardcoded the function name with window['at_26'] = function() {alert("Inside 26"); };

Comment: @MSach: You can almost always replace any literal with a variable. If `var a = 'at_26';` then you can write `window[a] = ...;` and `window[a]();`. No big deal.