# JS variable wont save when passing to another function

Tags: java, javascript

I am taking a value from a java applet and storing it i na variable in JS.  I then call an alert on this variable and the alert prints the correct value to screen but then when i call this variable again in the createApp function the variable prints as undefined and I have no idea why.  any help would be apprieciated

JS code:

```
var app = {


notLoaded : true,
dataVar : "hello",


testApplet : function(){


    while(app.notLoaded){
        if(typeof myApplet.testString != 'undefined')
        {

            app.notLoaded = false;
            this.dataVar = myApplet.testString;
            alert(this.dataVar);
            //window.open("menuPage.html");
            app.createApp();

        }
    }
},


bluetoothPage : [ 0x10, [this.dataVar, "bluetoothMenu"], 
          0xA1, ["rpm2", "RPM2", "1500", "0", "3000"],
          0xA1, ["rpm3", "RPM3", "1500", "0", "3000"],
          0xD0],

createApp : function(){

        //document.write(app.bluetoothPage);
    app.createPage(menuPage);
    app.createPage(app.bluetoothPage);

      .........ect  } closes object
```

all the other parts of the bluetoothPage work fine when the menu is written just the variable this.dataVar goes from being Hello World to undefined

Answer (score 0):

You strike the issue of **scope**. that variable dateVar is local to `app`. Make it global to access among the functions.

```
var appletdataVar="";
var app = {
```

And assign value inside app function.

```
 this.dataVar = myApplet.testString;
 alert(this.dataVar);
 appletdataVar=myApplet.testString;
```

Now you can access `appletdataVar` in another functions.

Comment: Ive tried that as well and still gives the same result.  plus that function is a method within the object app shouldnt it have access to app.dataVar?

Comment: Yes, Look here for syntax.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733580/javascript-variable-in-function-name-possible

Comment: ya thats how im using it, correct? except im using app.(some function) instead of app[somefunction]();  i didnt know you could use it that way.  The variable is still undefined in the property app.bluetooth property array