# Javascript function as a variable in loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, conditional-execution

Can you please help me with one loop with functions:

I have 7 functions:

```
function menu1(){};
function menu3(){};
function menu4(){};
function menu5(){};
function menu6(){};
function menu7(){};
```

And what i need to do is load as a function menux(){}
I mean from the loop if x == 3 load function menu3().

```
for(x=1;x=8;=x++)
{
    function menux(){};
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `function menu(num){ .. }`?

Comment: There is no way to make a *single* menu function that accepts a "menuNumber" argument?

Comment: What happened to `menu2`? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733580/javascript-variable-in-function-name-possible

Have a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your function into an object:

```
function menu1(){};
function menu3(){};
function menu4(){};
function menu5(){};
function menu6(){};
function menu7(){};

var wrap={
    menu1:menu1;
    menu3:menu3;
    menu4:menu4;
    menu5:menu5;
    menu6:menu6;
    menu7:menu7;
}
```

And then, you can cosume that into the for:

```
for(x=1;x=8;=x++)
{
  if(!wrap["menu"+i]) wrap["menu"+i]();
}
```

There are a lot of ways of doing that, you can also do:

```
function menu(int num){
 switch(num)
  {
   case 1:
    menu1();
    break;
   case 2:
    menu2();
    break;

   //....
  }
}
```

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably explain your situation and what you want to achieve in the bigger picture. This seems like a suboptimal approach already. But well, here you go:

```
for(var x=1; x<8; x++)
{
    window['menu' + x]();
}
```

Assumuing your function declarations are in global namespace, this loop will call all those functions from `menu1` to `menu7`.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask yourself - if there's a different way. And of course it is!

1. I suggest you to make a function which accept an argument and does something based on it like:
   `function menu(x) {...}`
2. If the first option is not available for you, I would suggest you do implement an object with these methods like this:

   `var methods = {
   menu1: function() {},
   menu2: function() {},
   menu3: function() {},
   ...
   }`
3. use `eval`. Please don't do that in this case. Eval is powerful but in such cases it's an overkill.