# Jscript - Variable in function name, possible?

Tags: windows, function, variables, jscript, wsh

I have a function names in array in WSH Jscript, I need to call them in a loop. 
Al what I found is here [Javascript - Variable in function name, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733580/javascript-variable-in-function-name-possible) but this doesn't work, maybe because I use WSH and/or run the script from console, not browser.

```
var func = [
    'cpu'
];

func['cpu'] = function(req){
    WScript.Echo("req="+req);
    return "cpu";
}

for (var item in func) {
    WScript.Echo("item="+ func[item](1));
}
```

The result is:

```
C:\test>cscript b.js
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.

C:\test\b.js(11, 2) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Function expected
```

(this is WScript.Echo line)

So, is there any way to call function using name in variable in this environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem is not WSH not command line.

This is what you have in your code:

```
var func = [
    'cpu'
];
```

that is, an array with one element in it. The content of the element is 'cpu' and its index is 0. Array length is 1.

```
func['cpu'] = function(req){
    WScript.Echo("req="+req);
    return "cpu";
}
```

This adds an aditional property to the array object not one element to the array content. If you test, array length is still 1.

```
for (var item in func) {
    WScript.Echo("item="+ func[item](1));
}
```

This iterates over the content of the array. `item` retrieves the index of each element in the array and then is used to retrieve the content. But the content of the array is only one element, with index 0 and its contents is a string (`cpu`). It is not a function, so, you can not call it.

The problem is you are mixing the way to work with objects and the way to work with arrays.

For an array version

```
var func = [
    function cpu(req){
        return 'called cpu('+req+')';
    },
    function other(req){
        return 'called other('+req+')';
    }
];

func.push(
    function more(req){
        return 'called more('+req+')';
    }
);

for (var item in func) {
    WScript.Echo('calling func['+item+']='+ func[item](1));
};
```

For a objects version

```
var func = {
    cpu : function(req){
        return 'called cpu('+req+')';
    },
    other : function(req){
        return 'called other('+req+')';
    }
};

func['more'] = function(req){
    return 'called more('+req+')';
};

for (var item in func) {
    WScript.Echo('calling func['+item+']='+ func[item](1));
};
```

As you can see, very similar, but if you work with arrays, then you should add elements to the array, not properties, as the `for in` will iterate over the elements in the array. In the case of the  object approach, you add properties to an object and the `for in` iterates over the properties of the object.

Very similar, but not the same.