# Are 'combinations whose operators are themselves compound expressions' synonymous with Variable Functions?

Tags: function, scheme, evaluation, function-call

I apologize in advance for lacking some vocabulary here. Going through [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%25_sec_1.1.6), there is an early reference to 'combinations whose operators are themselves compound expressions', e.g.:

```lisp
(define (a-plus-abs-b a b)
  ((if (> b 0) + -) a b))
```

where the combination `(if (> b 0) + -)` is evaluated as either a `+` or `-`, which is then evaluated as e.g. `(+ a b)` if b is greater than zero.

My question is: Is this different from a variable function (e.g. [in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)), and how so? Also, do variable functions and this functionality differ from using [Javascript-style object references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733580/javascript-variable-in-function-name-possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important notion here, from the Lisp perspective, is whether a language is a 'lisp-1' or a 'lisp-2'.  The difference between these two is: in an expression which looks like a function application, how is the thing which will represent the function to be applied evaluated?

So, in Lisps something which looks like a function application looks like a list:

```
(f a b ...)
```

When considering such a thing the system has to do three things:

1. establish that it *is* a function application (so, for instance, `(if ...)` is not, and neither is a form which is a macro);
2. if it is, evaluate the function and its arguments;
3. call the function, passing it the result of evaluating its arguments.

(Note: I have assumed what is called *applicative-order* evaluation here: a *normal-order* language does things differently.)

And the question is how (2) happens.

- A *lisp-1* evaluates the function position (the first position) in such a form in exactly the same way as all the other positions.  Thus the function position can contain a completely arbitrary expression.  So `((if add + -) 1 2)` is perfectly fine, as is `(let ((op ...)) (op ...))` for instance.
- A *lisp-2* uses some special rule for the function position, and in particular for a lisp-2 the 'function value' of a symbol lives in a different namespace to the ordinary value.  This means that what is allowed there is *not* a general expression, but rather whatever the rules allow.  So, for instance, in a lisp-2, something like this does not work:  `(let ((op (lambda ...))) (op ...))`, but something like this *does* work: `(let ((car ...)) (car car))`.

Famously, Scheme is a lisp-1, Common Lisp is a lisp-2.

So then the way to answer your question, I think, is to realise that this notion can be applied perfectly well to other languages.

- JavaScript is a lisp-1, so the function position of things that look like function applications is just evaluated perfectly normally.
- Python is a lisp-1.
- I don't know what PHP is.

Note that in these languages the way you know that something is a function application is completely different than it is in Lisp, but the important question is, once you do know that, how do you evaluate the function position?

Comment: wouldn't we need to `funcall` that `let`-defined `car`?

Comment: @WillNess: We would if we wanted to call it, but I want to call the ordinary `car` function.  Obviously this would be awful code in practice: I confess to things like `(destructuring-bind (first . rest) ... ...)` but I'd then try to avoid saying `(first first)` in the body, because it's just gratuitously confusing.

Comment: ah, so you meant that let-defined `car` to be some data, not a function...

Answer (score 2):

In Scheme (which is used by SICP) one can use variables in function position.

First we try to use the symbol `+` as a function:

**Trying to use a symbol as a function**

```
> (define foo '+)
> foo
+
> (foo 1 2)
Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure +
```

Unfortunately this does not work: `foo` evaluates to the symbol `+` and this is itself not a function

**Using a function object**

But this works:

```
> (define foo +)
> (foo 1 2)
3
```

Here `foo` was set to the value of `+`, which is a function object. The `foo` will also evaluate to that object. Thus `(foo 1 2)` evaluates to `3`.

Answer (score 2):

All functions in JavaScript are variables and it allows expressions in operator position:

```js
function plus (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

plus; // => [Function: plus]

function minus (a, b) {
  return a - b
}

minus; // => [Function: minus]

function plusAbs (a, b) {
  return (b > 0 ? plus : minus)(a, b);
}

plusAbs(3, -3); // => 6
plusAbs(3, 3);  // => 6

var plus = 4;
plus; // => 4 (no longer a function)
plusAbs(3, 3);  // ERROR! 4 is not a function
```

Just as Scheme it **doesn't** evaluate to `plus` or `minus` but rather what `plus` and `minus` evaluates to. Eg. the `[function minus]` and **not** the variable.

Functions in PHP cannot be done this way by name, but variables bound to functions:

```php
function plusAbs ($a, $b) { 
  $add = function($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }; 
  $sub = function($a, $b) { return $a-$b; }; 
  return ($b < 0 ? $sub : $add)($a, $b); 
}
plusAbs(3, -3); // => 6
```

Closest you get with named functions:

```php
function add($a, $b) { return $a+$b; }
function sub($a, $b) { return $a-$b; }

function plusAbs ($a, $b) { 
  return call_user_func($b < 0 ? 'sub' : 'add', $a, $b); 
}
plusAbs(3, -3); // => 6
```

Note that this no longer has expression in operator position.