# How can I have variable (string) in function's name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to call a function whose name is in a variable like this:

```
const funcNames = [
  "func1",
  "func2",
  "func3"
];

someElem.funcNames[0](someArg);
```

Here I want funcName's 0 index element to be the name of the function I want to call on someElem (with args)

I hope I was able to explain

and I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3733580/14527864) but its not what I want.

Thanks

Comment: The correct syntax would be `someElem[funcNames[0]]`

Comment: I think you did not understood what I want

Comment: someElem and square bracket will mean that I want the elem at funcNames[0] index and someElem is an array or object